# How to change attribute values of a activity using clear-case commands?

Tags: command-line, clearcase

I want to change the values of the clear-case activity attributes. Can anyone give me commands which I can use in a windows command prompt.

```
activity "<activity_id>"
  created 2015-05-04by ayz
  master replica: <xxx>
  owner: <owner>
  group: <group>
  stream: <stream>
  title: <title>
  change set versions:
    xxx.java@@\main\...\5
  Attributes:
    activity_ok = "yes"
    Delivered = "no"
    Finished = "no"
    Type_Activity = "User"
```

I want to change the values of the attributes `Delivered` and `Finished` to "Yes".

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible using [`cleartool mkattr`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkattr.htm):

```
cleartool mkattr -replace Delivered \"yes\" activity:activity_id@\aPVob
```